# Dynamic information flow between ROSJAVA nodes and ROSActivity

Tags: ros, android-core, ros-fuerte, threads, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

When using ROSJAVA with android I'd like to pass information from the ROSActivity gui to the ros_node implementing nodeMain. Is there a way to do this without using the normal ROS message traffic?

If there is, how is it done?

cheers

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55582/dynamic-information-flow--between-rosjava-nodes-and-rosactivity/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a lot of options here. You're basically asking how to write a multi-threaded Activity. This tutorial seems to cover a lot of the various concepts:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-03-01**:
I looked at the handlers type of processing but in the tutorial, it mentioned that it must be run in the same scope as the main activity. I attribute my failure to the fact that I'm trying to update a handler inside my class and therefore out of scope. What method do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based off Damon's answer, I applied the transfer of information between threads by using an application class as described in his link and elaborated [here](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android#)

To use the application class which contains the data I wanted to transfer. I created a global instance in the mainActivity onCreate() method, then I created my node classes, passing the instance of the application to them like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rApplication = (ROSApplication)getApplicationContext();
        interfacenode= new cartesian_interface_node(rApplication);
        statusupdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }
```

After the in the init() method after all the nodes had been set running by the nodeMainExecutor, I passed to a function called loop() and placed the following code.

```
protected void loop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                statusupdate.setText(rApplication.Status);
            }
        });
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

there's probably a more correct way to implement the loop other than the while loop, but it is effective and the update to ui works! The power of Android UI and ROS!

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1